# Android: Can I check if my app's notification is still in the status bar?

Tags: android, notifications, status

My app pops up a message count notification and sets it as "ongoing". There is a timer that re-sends the notification every 5 minutes, and the notification has the flag `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` , so that it can only get cleared by my app. And my app is set up to only use sound and vibrate if the count changes.

So, the idea is that if my app changes the count, it sends out an updated notification, which replaces the old one, and plays a sound and vibrates. But if the 5 minute timer tries to update the notification, but the count didn't change, the notification is still sent. but without sound or vibrate. This is done in case the notification somehow got cleared, I want it to pop back up, but if it's still there, I don't want the user to be re-notified.

I also save the message count so that it's remembered if the app is closed and then re-opened. The problem is that when that happens (if it's force-closed, for example), the old notification stays in the bar, but the newly opened app has no idea that's the case. So I'd like to be able to somehow poll the notification service to see if that original notification is still showing, but I can't find any API to do this. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I'd like to be able to somehow poll the notification service to see if that original notification is still showing, but I can't find any API to do this. Is it possible?

No.

However, you can use `deleteIntent` to find out if the user cleared the `Notification`. Either that, or track down the cause of your "somehow got cleared" issue.